# Voltage fluctuation on heavy load

Tags: voltage, parallel

why voltage fluctuation happen in houses when we connect heavy load ?
since all the houses are in parallel,so all of them recieve same voltage..then why voltage fluctuation is there? and why not current fluctuation?
why voltage stabilizers are used not current stabilizers ??

**I mean it is the Property of parallel connection that it doesn't matter how many load you add in parallel, all of the load share same voltage**

Comment: Parasitic inductance and resistance, the wires can't deliver power instantaneously from the grid

Answer (score 2):

You're assuming that electrical conductors have zero resistance.  In the real World, copper wires have a small resistance per metre.  So if you change the load at the far end from the supply, the voltage drops.

You wouldn't want a current stabilizer as it would cause problems when you switch appliances on and off.  The current is supposed to change, while the voltage remains constant.

Answer (score 0):

If the street is very long and the supply is from one end, then the voltage will drop at the other end as a function of the losses (I^2 * R).

People on the end of a long power transmission line do experience this - especially in remote areas.